# Why are complex arithmetic operation not allowed in the while condition in python

Tags: python

This function finds the number of digits in a number

```
def getNumOfDigits(i):
    num = i
    count = 1
    num = num // 10
    while num != 0:
        count += 1
        num //= 10
    return count
```

If I try to modify the while condition to divide num by 10 and check if it is not equal to 0 it throws up a syntax error. Why is this so in python?

```
def getNumOfDigits(i):
num = i
count = 1
while (num //= 10)!= 0:
    count += 1
return count
```

Answer (score 4):

Assignment such as `num //= 10` is a statement and cannot be part of an expression.

> Why is this so in python?

Recently it was decided that assignment should be allowed in expressions in certain situations and this caused a huge controversy, see [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/757713/) for more.

Comment: but you can say about [pep-0572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Comment: Thank you for the link to this very interesting article!